# How do I limit an ActiveRecord query, then run a "where" clause?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

I'm trying to find responses for a survey, limiting the number of responses to the limit specified on the user's plan, then for each choice, I want to find how many responses there are. My current query looks like this:

```
Response.joins(choice: { question: :survey })
    .where(surveys: { id:survey.id })
    .limit(plan.response_limit)
    .where(choice: object)
```

However, this query runs the "where" clauses, *then* limits the query. Could someone please tell me how to write a query that does what I want?

Edit:

The query I posted produces the following SQL:

```
 SELECT  "responses".* FROM "responses" 
 INNER JOIN "choices" ON "choices"."id" = "responses"."choice_id" 
 INNER JOIN "questions" ON "questions"."id" = "choices"."question_id" 
 INNER JOIN "surveys" ON "surveys"."id" = "questions"."survey_id" 
 WHERE "surveys"."id" = 1 AND "responses"."choice_id" = 1 
 LIMIT 5000
```

Edit 2: SQL formatting

Comment: what's the SQL this produces and what SQL do you expect?

Comment: Edit: I added the SQL to the post itself.

I don't know what the SQL query should look like, but I know what I want to do: I want to find the responses for a given survey, limit the results to, say, 5000, then find the number of responses for a given choice id within those limited results.

Comment: This is what a SQL query normally looks like. The LIMIT clause is always listed at the end of the query. It doesn't mean that it goes and fetches them all out and then runs a limit... it's just how it's written as per standard.

Comment: I see, thanks @TarynEast!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`from`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-from) method to SELECT from a subquery:

```
subquery = Response.joins(choice: { question: :survey })
  .where(surveys: { id:survey.id })
  .limit(plan.response_limit)

responses = Response.from(subquery, :resp)
  .where(choice: object)
```

I'm not 100% sure how Rails deals with subqueries behind the scenes, so you might have to tweak that into something like this instead:

```
responses = Response.from(subquery)
  .where("resp.choice_id = ?", object)
```

Comment: I tried both queries, and both return the same error:

`PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "responses"
LINE 1: SELECT "responses".* FROM (SELECT  "responses".* FROM "respo...`

Edit: trimmed the error message

Comment: I've edited my answer to use a table alias (`resp`), which I think will fix the error. I've never actually used this feature, though, so more finesse might be necessary.

Comment: I tried using a table alias, but I'm getting the same error. I'll have to read up on the "from" method and subqueries -- this is unfamiliar territory.